# Question about the homotopy related to mappings $f,g: X \to S^n$ continuous maps such that $f(x)+g(x)\ne 0$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be a space and $f,g: X \to S^n$ continuous maps such that $f(x)+g(x)\ne 0$ for every $x \in X$. Show that $f \simeq g$.

The condition $f(x)+g(x)\ne 0$ implies that there isn't any $x \in X$ for which $f$ and $g$ are antipodal. I've found the solution to the problem online and what they did was they first considered the linear homotopy $$h'(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)+ tg(x)$$ from where they constructed $$h(x,t)= \dfrac{h'(x,t)}{|h'(x,t)|}$$ and apparently this satisfies as the homotopy between $f$ and $g$.

This had something to do with the fact that since $f(x)+g(x) \ne 0$ the line from $h'$ never passes thourgh the origin. What I don't understand is how this constructed $h$ works as the homotopy as $$h(x,0)= \dfrac{f(x)}{|f(x)|} \ne f(x)$$ and $$h(x,1)=\dfrac{g(x)}{|g(x)|} \ne g(x).$$

Why are we doing this normlization here?

Comment: For each $x\in X$ we have $f(x)\in S^n$, and so $|f(x)|=1$. So $\frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}$ is indeed equal to $f(x)$. Same thing for $g$.

Comment: I see. I missed that... Although why isn't the homotopy $h'$ working by itself?

Comment: Because $h'(x,t)$ might not belong to $S^n$. So we have to normalize it.

Comment: Taking this down to $S^1$ I think that $h'$ gives me line segments between the points $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ so the problem is when for example $t = 1/2$ and I'll get a point inside the sphere not on the boundary?

Comment: @Mark Do you happen to know what is the problem if we let $f(x_0) = -g(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in X$? It breaks continuity somehow?

Comment: you have to set the condition $f(x_0)\not=-g(x_0)$ (i.e. $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$ are not antipodal) becouse $h(x_0,t)$ normalizes the point between  $f(x_0)$ and $g(x_0)$ and you  can't normalizes $h(x_0,\frac{1}{2})=0 $(if they are antipodal)